# update cosmos db gremlin vertices using document API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Can I use cosmos Document APIs to bulk update gremlin api vertices and edges? we are a java shop and Microsoft doesn't have a java client to do bulk imports into cosmos DB gremlin APIs. It is doable, but is it recommended?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java Bulk executor library for Azure CosmosDB Gremlin API.
Please find more details here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-bulk-executor-java

Samples are provided on Github

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-java-getting-started

An overview of Azure Cosmos DB bulk executor library is here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview

Comment: yes, but how do i use these APIs to store graph vertices and edges?